# How to ensure Anonymous login with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a React Native application which use Firebase Auth uid to identify individual user instances.
My initial implementation called `signInAnonymously` on every starting up and it returned non-persistent uid.

Referring to [Anonymous user in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195616/anonymous-user-in-firebase), my code became like this. it works as expected but still unclear why this code is correct.

```
static ensureLogin() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        resolve(user)
      } else {
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
          .catch(function(error) {
            reject()
          })
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, let's check details in this official document.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

It has this example code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

The latter comment line says "No user is signed in." instead of "User is signed out.".
It implies that it is triggered not only by user's sign in/out actions.

It also says below.

> By using an observer, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an
>   intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current
>   user.

This means that 2 facts.

1. Auth object has internal states
2. `onAuthStateChanged` observes the state of Auth object

So, we should notice that `onAuthStateChanged` can be triggered by any status change of Auth object including initialization! And calling `signInAnonymously` after init is nothing strange.

Once `signInAnonymously` in else block is called, it re-triggers `onAuthStateChanged` after signing in.

That's why the code is correct.